# In the Django-admin, interleave readonly and (regular) editable fields

Tags: django-admin

In my Django admin, there are a few fields that I would like to define as read only. If I use `readonly_fields`, these float to the bottom of the page. This is not desirable in my use case, I want to preserve the ordering I had before I set them as read only. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelAdmin.readonly_fields` not affect on fields_order and not add any additional field in `AdminForm` if `fields` or `fieldsets` are defined.

in normal mode:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):    
    fields = 'title', 'description', 'my_first_readonly', 'visible'
    readonly_fields = 'my_first_readonly', 'my_second_readonly'
```

The order of fields should be `'title'`, `'description'`, `'my_first_readonly'`, `'visible'`. `'my_second_readonly'` not appears, because it not listed in `fields`.

more info here:

### fields

how it works with readonly:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields

### readonly fields.

you can find mention about field ordering there:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Only one reason, why order of fields can change itself:
`ModelAdmin.get_fields` or/and `ModelAdmin.get_fieldsets` are overridden

more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields